# What does The Saharan Republic's power mean?

Tags: risk-legacy

One of the starting powers for The Saharan Republic says

> You can make your maneuver at any point during your turn.

Does this mean they can attack, maneuver, and then continue to attack?

Comment: Do you have a different interpretation for this power? It has to give you _some_ advantage - what else could it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is exactly what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [these rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/documents/dad2886d1c4311ddbd0b0800200c9a66/00D721465056900B10A16E11F8F54E7F.pdf), a turn consists of the following:

> 1. Start of Turn
> 2. Join the War or Recruit Troops
> 3. Expand & Attack (optional)
> 4. Maneuver Troops (optional)
> 5. End of Turn

The Saharan Republic special ability allows you to ignore the timing of step 4. It doesn't allow you to carry out any extra maneuvers, nor change what a maneuver does.

The main use of the ability is to move troops to an aggressive position before or between attacks. It can also be used during the "End of Turn" phase, to

> maneuver the extra troop generated by a mercenary scar to a defensive position, which would normally be created after the maneuver,

or to

> maneuver troops to react to an event card drawn during the end of turn.